# Align Message and Submit button to the right of other input fields

Tags: css, input, css-float

[Live site.](http://www.frshstudio.com/contact/)

I'm having a small issue styling a contact form. I'd like for the message field and submit button to be to the right of all other input fields, aligned along the top. When I use `clear:both` and `float:right`, the message and submit button DO move over, however they are well below all other fields.
How do I fix this?

```
.contact_name {
    font-family: fanwood-webfont;
    margin-left: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.contact_email {
    font-family: fanwood-webfont;
    margin-left: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.contact_subject {
    font-family: fanwood-webfont;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

.contact_message {
    clear: both;
    float: right;
    font-family: fanwood-webfont;
}

.contact_button {
    clear: both;
    float: right;
}
```

&

```
<p class=contact_name>Name (required)<br />
[text* your-name]</p>

<p class=contact_email>Email (required)<br />
[email* your-email]</p>

<p class=contact_subject>Subject<br />
[text* your-subject]</p>

<p class=contact_message>Message<br />
[textarea* your-message]</p>

<p>[submit class:contact_button "Send"]</p>
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to you create two `<div>` elements, one `left floated` and second `right`. 

You need `float` property basically.

**Basic example:**

```
​#left {
   width: 150px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: #eeeeee;
   float: left;
}

​#right {
   width: 150px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: #eeeeee;
   float: right;
}​
```

Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gGWZG/).

Comment: np, i'm glad that i help you.

Answer (score 0):

You must put the floated elements before the static ones to show them on the same beginning length :)

So in your case simply like this:

```
<p class=contact_message>Message<br />
[textarea* your-message]</p>

<p>[submit class:contact_button "Send"]</p>

<p class=contact_name>Name (required)<br />
[text* your-name]</p>

<p class=contact_email>Email (required)<br />
[email* your-email]</p>

<p class=contact_subject>Subject<br />
[text* your-subject]</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write like this:

**HTML**

```
<p class=contact_message>Message<br />
[textarea* your-message]</p>

<p>[submit class:contact_button "Send"]</p>

<p class=contact_name>Name (required)<br />
[text* your-name]</p>

<p class=contact_email>Email (required)<br />
[email* your-email]</p>

<p class=contact_subject>Subject<br />
[text* your-subject]</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.contact_message,
.contact_message + p{
   float: right;
}

.contact_name,
.contact_email,
.contact_subject {
   float: left;
}
```